# Can we kill the unicorn?

Tags: support, april-fools, unikong

Yeah yeah I know we *shouldn't* kill the Unicorn, and I've tried blasting him with the gun way  more than I'm willing to admit, but... is there a way to kill the unicorn who tries to kill us?

Apart of blasting with the gun I tried to jump on him, and sadly can't think of other ways.

If possible somehow, will we get any reputation for killing him, or more likely suffer a reputation penalty for doing such a horrible thing? :)

Comment: HNQ [Can I ride the unicorn? If not, can I kill the unicorn?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/260963)

Comment: @DavidPostill LOL, never imagined someone will ask on arqade, but thinking about it, this makes perfect sense!

Comment: The fact that the unicorn doesn't fart rainbows when you shoot it in the behind is a major bug

Comment: Kill a unicorn? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2pmcAjvWYQ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about the 2016 April Fool's joke feature. Since it was undeployed a long time ago, questions about it aren't relevant anymore.

Comment: @Sonic while I don't oppose the closure itself, I think it's pointless and bumping the question back to the front for no good reason. Thousands of questions can be closed with that reason, but for what? They have no activity, they cause no trouble. Closing many questions will just flood the homepage with noise. (Didn't happen yet, but it can if we're not careful.) Proper solution can be option for moderators to mass-close many questions (e.g. with certain tag) **silently** without it bumping all those questions. Anyway, guess this better be discussed in a new question... :)

Comment: Closing questions does *not* bump them. There haven't been any edits to this question, and it's unlikely to be reopened.

Answer (score 10):

Give [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0804138737) a read and see if it helps.

Comment: I don't want to spend money though!

Comment: Hey, [is this the book author](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1508475/mark-payne)? ;)

Comment: I never thought the day would come when SE was sold out and now all of its employees are shills for globalized unicorn hunting companies and advertising this book.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Answer (score 8):

Shooting it does slow it down, so if you're quick on the trigger you can get to the treasure faster.

Also, shooting unicorns is cathartic. If they actually died, you'd just be shooting a dead horse.

Comment: How dare you compare a unicorn to a horse!

Comment: They're not horses, of course - horses can die. Everyone knows this. Therefore, unicorns are *undead* horses. With weapons. I believe the game makes this rather obvious...